# Can we use "artifacts.require()" in react.js files?

Tags: truffle, react

When we write scripts for executing the functions of smart contracts we can use "artifacts.require()" in those vanilla javascript files. But If we use it in react.js files it gives an error telling that "artifacts" is not defined. So why is it happening? why can't we use "artifacts.require()" in react.js files even though we can use it in vanilla js files?

Answer (score 0):

you can use in truffle

```
 artifacts.require()
```

because in truffle.config.js, you already told truffle where to look for those artifacts.  Artifacts are JSON files of the contracts.

```
// truffle.config.js
module.exports = {
  // truffle reads from here
  contracts_directory: "./src/contracts",
  contracts_build_directory: "./src/abis",
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*",
    },
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.4",
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: but if we use vanilla js we can use "artifacts.require()". problem occurs when it comes to react. Is there any clarification to that?

Comment: @Jagath vanilla.js files are located inside truffle directories. if u get a .js file outside truffle directories and use artifacts, you will get errror,as well